# Viewstate and TabPanel

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, viewstate

I have been working on a asp.net project last ~6 months where that was one .aspx that was being loaded with different controls. This page and those controls had their own UpdatePanels, etc etc. In other words I had to deal with a bag of viewstate issues. It seems like whenever I think I get viewstate and its details completely I get something like what I am about to describe below. This might have to do with control state, which is from what I understand "necessary" viewstate you cannot turn off. Or this might have to do something with AJAX.
  Anyway take a look at this example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="ControlDisabledViewStateTesting._Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="C#" runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (treeView.SelectedNode != null)
                ContentPanel.Controls.Add(ContentPanel.TemplateControl.LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx"));
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>    
        <ajx:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" />    
        <asp:TreeView ID="treeView" runat="server">
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="First Node" Value="111"/>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Second Node" Value="222"/>
            </Nodes>
        </asp:TreeView>        
        <Asp:Panel ID="ContentPanel" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the user control mark up:

```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="ControlDisabledViewStateTesting.MyUserControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajx" %>
<ajx:TabContainer ID="tabContainer" ActiveTabIndex="0" runat="server">
    <ajx:TabPanel ID="tab" HeaderText="Tab1" runat="server"/>            
    <ajx:TabPanel ID="tab2" HeaderText="Tab2" runat="server" />            
</ajx:TabContainer>
```

As you have noticed, Viewstate is turned off on the page level, so none of the controls should be using viewstate. 
  Click on "First Node".
  User control gets loaded with two tabs. 
  Select the second tab.
  Click on "Second Node"
  User controls get loaded again, with the "SECOND TAB" selected already.

Is this an issue with viewstate/controlstate or does it have something to do with AJAX part of the TabPanel?

I really appreciate if someone can shed some lights as to what is happening here and how I can turn off this functionality.

Thanks,
  Mike

Answer (score 0):

The value for the active tab isn't being stored in view state.  It appears to have to do with the ASP.NET AJAX framework and the value is being loaded from the post data.

To change the behavior you could derive from the TabContainer and override the LoadClientState method so that the ActiveTabIndex isn't changed.

You can view the source code for the TabContainer on codeplex:
http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1014bf767f65#Server%2fAjaxControlToolkit%2fTabs%2fTabContainer.cs